# Docker and Nginx proxy_pass between containers

Tags: django, nginx, docker, proxy, gunicorn

I'm trying to run configuration with Docker, Nginx, Gunicorn and Django.

Currently I successfully managed to run my container with Gunicorn and Django app using this command:

```
docker run --publish 8003:8000 user/app:latest
```

Now when I connect to localhost:8003 I see my application running.

At this point I would like to set up my Nginx in container to point to this app whenever I browse to `localhost/app`

My Nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
...
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /app {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
      }
}
...
```

I run it with:

```
docker run --publish 80:80 user/nginx:latest
```

This does not work and I can't wrap my head around this, thanks for any ideas how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localhost IP `127.0.0.1` inside your nginx only refers internally to the nginx container.  There are a couple of solutions to this, either:

1. The simple thing is to run your nginx container in "host-mode networking" mode. At this point, `127.0.0.1` actually refers to your container host and it should all be good. See [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-host), but basically just adding `--network="host"` should work. The downside with this simplicity is that it's slightly less secure.
2. Alternatively, you can use "linked" containers, see [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) where you want the `--link` option. This way, from inside the nginx container you can use DNS resolution to access a different container, so you'd update your `proxy_pass` to the linked name. As a side note, doing this from [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) makes things considerably easier.